# Android Spinner list only pulling 1 column

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, spinner

I have a spinner that pulls its list of text from an SQLite DB, but it is only pulling one column, the second one (the first being ID). I did not write most of the code to pull from the DB, I found a tutorial and modified it to fit what I needed. What I would like is for it to pull the first row, columns 2 and 3, then move on the second row until all the rows have been entered. My DB is ID, BARNAME, BARCITY. I would like to pull BARNAME then have a comma, then pull BARCITY. All help is appreciated. I'm not looking to have the code written for me, I'm trying to better understand the code that I found and how it works so that I can modify it for my program.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sixth;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
OnItemSelectedListener {
    DBHelper myDB;
    Button btnSetCity;  
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDB = new DBHelper(this);
         // Spinner element
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
     // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



        try {
            myDB.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            myDB.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }

        // Loading spinner data from database
        loadSpinnerData();
    }


     private void loadSpinnerData() {
            // database handler
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

            // Spinner Drop down elements
            List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.sixth;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.sixth/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "BarSample.db"; 
    private final Context myContext;    
    public static String tableName = "Bars";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String BARNAME = "Bar Name";
    public static final String BARCITY = "Bar City";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                this.close();
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableName;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;

    } // will returns all labels stored in database
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/select_location"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/select_location"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:entries="@array/locations" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSetCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/set_city"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A tutorial is meant to teach you something. If you come here to have other people modify the code you copied from that tutorial, then (1) you didn't learn anything, and (2) you need a consultant or programmer. Your question is too broad. Try to understand the code you copied -- maybe read the prose that goes with it? Then try to make the required changes yourself. If you still fail, come back here!

Comment: There was just code. No explanation, no video showing how it works or why. I've tried looking the information up elsewhere, for about 4 hours now, but was unable to find something that helped me better understand it. That's why I came here, hoping that someone could help me better understand, not write the code for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your following line..

```
labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
```

Here you are fetching only one column.. You need to show the data as BarName,BarCity correct.?

Then modify the above line as follows..

```
labels.add(cursor.getString(1) + ", " + cursor.get string(2));
```

This will do your work..

Comment: And if, for example, I wanted to show the ID for some reason, I would use labels.add(cursor.getString(0) + ", "+cursor.getString(1) + ", " + cursor.get string(2)); ?

Comment: That's correct.. The number 0,1,2 refers to the column numbers in the order you kept while creating database

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Teaching myself and after 5 or 6 hours of staring at the same result, the brain cells start to sizzle a bit.